# Excel 2013 - Double dependent dropdown and VLookUp to create Sales Quote

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vlookup

Fairly specific problem in Excel. I am trying to create a dependent dropdown that is dependent on a dependent dropdown. I then want to use `VLookUp` to find the corresponding price of the combination of 'product type' 'product' and 'product options' and populate the sales quote with that data.

Here is a visual representation:

[image]

Comment: Something like [THIS?](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/29/excel-data-validationcreate-dynamic-dependent-lists-vba/)

Comment: Yes, except I have Excel 2013 -- will the VBA code still work? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tested it in Excel 2013 but I guess it should.